# jQuery/JS stop loop setTimeout on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a map with multiple cities on it. I also have a loop showing the details of each city. I would like to completely stop the loop once I click on one of the cities.

I tried with: clearTimeout(loopIdx) but it didn't work. Could you please help me?! Cheers.

**LOOP:**

```
$(function() {
 var $mapCol = $('.map-col');
 var $mapBtn = $('.map-btn');
 var $mapLoops = $('.map-loop');
 var $btnLoops = $('.btn-loop');
 loopIdx = (function _loop(idx) {
    $mapCol.removeClass('active-map');
    $mapBtn.removeClass('active-btn');
    $mapLoops.removeClass('active-map').eq(idx).addClass('active-map');
    $btnLoops.removeClass('active-btn').eq(idx).addClass('active-btn');

    setTimeout(function() {
     _loop((idx + 1) % $mapLoops.length);
        }, 6000);
     }(0));
});
```

**BTN:**

```
<div class="btn-loop">City</div>
```

Comment: `setTimeout` returns a numeric id that you pass to `clearTimeout`.

Comment: Change `setTimeout` to `return setTimeout` so that `loopIdx` is set to its value.

Comment: I tried `$('btn-loop').click(function() { clearTimeout(loopIdx);});` but it didn't work. @Barmar

Comment: `$('btn-loop')` should be `$('.btn-loop')` you forgot the `.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the result of `setInterval()` to a variable, and use that in the `clearTimeout()` call.

```js
$(function() {
  var $mapCol = $('.map-col');
  var $mapBtn = $('.map-btn');
  var $mapLoops = $('.map-loop');
  var $btnLoops = $('.btn-loop');
  var timer;
  loopIdx = (function _loop(idx) {
    $mapCol.removeClass('active-map');
    $mapBtn.removeClass('active-btn');
    $mapLoops.removeClass('active-map').eq(idx).addClass('active-map');
    $btnLoops.removeClass('active-btn').eq(idx).addClass('active-btn');

    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      _loop((idx + 1) % $mapLoops.length);
    }, 2000);
  }(0));
  $btnLoops.click(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  });
});
```

```css
.map-loop.active-map {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-loop">City</div>
<div class="map-loop">1</div>
<div class="map-loop">2</div>
<div class="map-loop">3</div>
<div class="map-loop">4</div>
<div class="map-loop">5</div>
<div class="map-loop">6</div>
<div class="map-loop">7</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the timeoutID by name or identifier to clear it. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout.)

If you want `loopIdx` to be the identifier, you can use something like:

```
let needToClear = false;
let loopIdx = setTimeout(function(){}, 6000);
// ...state changes here...
if(needToClear){ clearTimeout(loopIdx); }
```

Comment: thanks for your help but how do I attach that to the button?

Comment: You add an event listener to the button and include the code in the listener's function body. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/eventlistener.)
For example: `const myBtn = document.querySelector("btn-loop"); myBtn.addEventListener("click", myFunc); function myFunc(){ /* loop and setTimeout code go here */ }`